# Using Excel solver function in a looping VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I'm trying write an Excel looping macro using the Solver function in excel.

After each iteration in the loop I need formulas on the worksheet to recalculate, however it seems as if sometime during the loop the calculation is set to manual even though I did not code it to do such (at least not intentionally).

Ideally I would like my workbook to calculate all formulas at the beginning of my loop prior to it using the solver function.

I've attached the code I currently have.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Lineups_Generator()
'
' Lineups_Generator Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("DK Lineups").Select
    Range("Output").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    E = Range("NumberOFLineups").Value
    T = 7


    For I = 1 To E

    Calculate


    SolverOk SetCell:="$Q$12", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$H$4:$H$203", _
      Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverSolve Userfinish:=True

    Sheets("DK Lineups").Select
    Range("Lineup").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(T, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    T = T + 1

    Next

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: why not move this before the loop: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` ...  Also, the copy paste can be written in 2 lines: `Sheets("DK Lineup").Range("Lineup")Copy (new line) Cells(T,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I've tried using the Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic before the loop, but that doesn't seem to work.  I had that code at the end because when I finished running the macro the calculations were always set to manual, which leads me to believe at some point during the loop the calculation is set to manual.

Comment: did you step-through it line-by-line and see in fact which line sets the calcs to manual?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman It seems to be the lines of solver code

Comment: I don't have time to research more now, set calcs back to auto after that line.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks, for your help but I realized the problem.  My code was never returning to the sheet in which Solver Function was set up on at the beginning of the loop so I thought the Solver Function was always returning the same values leading me to believe that the issue was due to the fact It wasn't updating the formulas within my sheet.  Sorry if I wasted any of your time.  Thanks again.

Comment: I was going to point out that you never referenced the worksheet  in `Cells(T,1)` but decided to leave it alone. Turns out that was the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it that the ScreenUpdating = False is the problem? I recall having this problem once.

The code might be trying to work with what is displayed, which may have been calculated behind the scenes but appears to be not calculated.
Try Rem (') before the ScreenUpdating statements to check this... remembering to step to the ... = True line to run just that line to ensure SU is set to update. Hope that makes sense